# set value to option button in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I create the option button like the following method,

```
{ name: 'Status', index: 'Status', width: 150, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'select', formatter: 'select', editoptions: { value: 'choose:--Choose---'} },
```

Am able to add only one value like choose. how to add more than one option in option button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
 editoptions: { value: 'choose:--Choose---'}
```

use this to add more options : I have added one, two

```
editoptions: { value: 'choose:--Choose---;1:one;2:two'}
```

where `1` = value and `one` = label of option

For more information on editoptions click **[here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3Acommon_rules)**.